# How to give least-squares lines the same colour as the respective data set in the scatter plot via MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have 3 different datasets from which I made a scatter plot. Different datasets I coded in different colours.

My code looks like that:

```
clear all;
close all;

% my colormap
colormap = [0, 0, 0
            0.5, 0.5, 0.5
            0,   0.5, 0.5];

% x values of 3 different datasets
xvalues = [10 20 30; 35 65 95; 22 42 82];

% y values of 3 different datasets
yvalues = [1 2 3; 6 12 24; 2 4 8];

figure;
axis([0 90  0 30]);

% loop for each dataset
for i = 1:3

    x = xvalues(i,:);    
    y = yvalues(i,:);
    scatter(x,y, 60, colormap(i,:));   hold on;    

end
```

Now, I would like to add least-squares lines for each of the dataset in the colour of the respective data set.

I added at the end of the code:

```
% add least-squares lines to scatter plot
h = lsline;
set(h,'linewidth',2,'color',colormap(i,:));
```

This will add the least-squares lines - all of them with the same color.

How can I give each of the least-squares lines the colour used for the respective datasets in the scatter plot

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lsline` will return [a vector of line objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lsline.html) if you have multiple plot objects on your axes. You will need to set the colors individually.

```
hlines = lsline;
for k = 1:numel(hlines)
    set(hlines(k), 'Color', colormap(k, :))
end
```

The way that you are doing it, you are setting *all* best-fit lines to be the color specified by `colormap(3,:)`.

[image]

If you use standard plot objects rather than `scatter` (there is no benefit to scatter here since you are using a constant color and size), then `lsline` should match the color of your object automatically. It *does not* do this for `scatter` plots as the color for each datapoint  typically varies.

```
figure;
axis([0 90  0 30]);

% loop for each dataset
for k = 1:3
    x = xvalues(k,:);    
    y = yvalues(k,:);
    plot(x, y, 'o', 'Color', colormap(k,:));
    hold on;    
end

lsline;
```

Comment: Thanks. Did I understand it right that replacing this:                                  h = lsline;
set(h,'linewidth',2,'color',colormap(i,:));                                                                                 by that code:
hlines = lsline;
for k = 1:numel(hlines)
    set(hlines(k), 'color', colormap(i, :))
end

should do the job? Unfortunately, I do get the same output.All lines have the same colour.

Comment: @annew It looks like you grabbed it while there was a typo. You are correct about which lines to replace however, it should be `colormap(k,:)` rather than `colormap(i,:)`. See the updated code above